# In Low Quality Queue, should I recommend deletion if the question is closed?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, low-quality-posts

I reviewed this post: https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/25999625

It seemed to me that it was good since the formatting is correct and there is an explanation text after the code.

But the post is flagged for spam or offensive content. After reading again I can't see what's offensive or spam. It is because the question is closed?

Comment: I don't see anything in that answer that warants a deletion. It is very likely that I would also have chose looks OK here. Audits are automatically picked by the system, but I don't really understand why this one was picked as a "known bad" audit" given that it was upvoted and got only deleted because the question was deleted.

Comment: The version actually posted by the OP was [this rather more spam like post](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/12824062/1) someone else then edited it into its current form. Kind of hard to figure out given the view you're shown of the post though.

Comment: @RobertLongson your link show Page not found

Comment: You would need 10K rep but it's basically a link to another site and the last 2 paragraphs of the original answer. The user name is part of the site name.

Comment: Ok so I should check the edit history too next time

Comment: I don't think this is a good audit, it's too hard to spot. Perhaps the mods can remove it from being a candidate. Not sure you even can check the edit history without 10K.

Comment: How can we tell them ?

Comment: You've already done all that's necessary by asking this question. I'm sure one will be along shortly.

Comment: @RobertLongson *"Not sure you even can check the edit history without 10K."* doesn't really matter, even *trying* to check the edit history (and getting the "this answer has been deleted" error) would show its an audit and push towards the correct action.

Answer (score 3):

Having the context of the question helps when reviewing the quality of the answer, but the fact that the question is closed or deleted is not a reason to impact your decision in the queue.

In this particular situation, you have fallen a victim to a bad audit. This is a very tricky post and ideally should not be used as an audit in LQP.

The post was deleted as spam by one of the moderators based on the first revision. https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/12824062/1

I assume there was more at play here (probably multiple spam posts linking to the same website) and the reason why a mod decided to delete it might never be revealed to us, but it is clear that the post was very suspicious and if it was not deleted I would definitely flag it for moderator's attention. If you check the poster's profile you can see their personal blog site. If you check the revisions you can see the code came from that website. While it is not a reason to cast a spam flag, it is definitely supposed to raise a red flag in your head.

This is also what you, as a reviewer should do. You need to pay as much attention to the post as possible and try to find out why is it in the queue and if anything (including flagging) should be done. If you check the revision and you see that some third party pasted in a code from the author's offsite link, then it would be the basis for a rollback and mod-flag. However, have you checked the revisions you would see the post is deleted as spam and then it would be a formality to click recommend deletion.

Audits are meant to stop you and make you think, but also to teach you what to pay attention to when curating the content. You have done well by coming to Meta to ask and learn. Great job!

Comment: *"You should not look too much at the question when reviewing the answers."* Citation very much needed. Have I been doing it wrong all these years?!

Comment: @cody I was referring to the state of the question. I removed the first sentence, because it was confusing.